# A question in Logic, equivalence relation

Tags: logic, compactness, first-order-logic

I have a question. I am pretty clueless on how to proceed with this question. I hope, that you guys are able to help me.

The question being:

Consider the language L* obtained by modifying LFOL= so that its only non-logical symbol is a two-place predicate $\equiv$. Let $\phi$ be the following sentence of L*:

($\forall$xx$\equiv$x$\wedge\forall$x$\forall$y(x$\equiv$y$\to$y$\equiv$x))$\wedge\forall$x$\forall$y$\forall$z((x$\equiv$y$\to$y$\equiv$z)$\to$x$\equiv$z))

A model I of s consists of a non-empty domain D and a function V assigning to $\equiv$ a two-place equivalence relation E on D.

a) Write a sentence $\psi$ of L* such that $\Gamma$ = {$\phi,\psi$} only has models I with domain D and a function V assigning to $\equiv$ a two-place equivalence relation E on D in which all elements are in the same equivalence class.

b) Write a sentence $\chi$ of L* such that $\Gamma$ = {$\phi,\chi$} only has models I with domain D and a function V assigning to $\equiv$ a two-place equivalence relation E on D in which all elements are in the same equivalence class.

Comment: Sorry if I missed it, but how do a) and b) differ?

Comment: My mistake. A typo.

Comment: How has this got anything to do with the title ?

Comment: So any relation must satisfy $\phi$ to be an equivalence relation - it must be reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Now think of when there would be only one equivalence class of all objects in a domain. Each element would have to bear $\equiv$ to each other element.